# Confusion about solution momentum problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

A man of mass $m$ is standing at one end of a stationary, floating barge of mass $3m$. He then walks to the other end of the barge, a distance of $L$ meters. Ignore any frictional effects between the barge and the water.

If the man walks at an average velocity of v, what is the average velocity of the barge?

I got to the answer of -v/3 using conservation of momentum; however, the solution got -v/4 by claiming that the barge moved -L/4 to the left over a period of time L/v and I cannot find a fallacy in the solution. Could someone enlighten me on whether I screwed up or the book is wrong.

EDIT : Is it possible the book is wrong because the CoM could move with constant velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CoM frame, net external force is zero as both bodies constitute CoM and by Newton's third law, these forces are equal. The fallacy lies in the fact that the man is walking with velocity 'v' in boat frame. So its velocity in CoM frame is not 'v'. You are applying momentum conservation in a frame thinking man moving towards right and boat towards left. But this frame is CoM frame where velocity of man is not 'v'. So switch to CoM frame and then calculate assuming some velocity of both man and boat. Apply momentum conservation along with the fact that 'relative' velocity is 'v'. Extend this line of thought.